# lsof survival guide

Tags: unix, system-administration, lsof

lsof is an increadibly powerful command-line utility for unix systems. It lists open files, displaying information about them. And since most everything is a file on unix systems, lsof can give sysadmins a ton of useful diagnostic data.

What are some of the most common and useful ways of using lsof, and which command-line switches are used for that?

Answer (score 124):

To show all networking related to a given `port`:

```
lsof -iTCP -i :port
lsof -i :22
```

To show connections to a specific host, use `@host`

```
lsof -i@192.168.1.5
```

Show connections based on the host and the port using `@host:port`
    lsof -i@192.168.1.5:22

`grep`ping for `LISTEN` shows what ports your system is waiting for connections on:

```
lsof -i| grep LISTEN
```

Show what a given user has open using `-u`:

```
lsof -u daniel
```

See what files and network connections a command is using with `-c`

```
lsof -c syslog-ng
```

The `-p` switch lets you see what a given process ID has open, which is good for learning more about unknown processes:

```
lsof -p 10075
```

The `-t` option returns just a `PID`

```
lsof -t -c Mail
```

Using the `-t` and `-c` options together you can `HUP` processes

```
kill -HUP $(lsof -t -c sshd)
```

You can also use the `-t` with `-u` to kill everything a user has open

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -u daniel)
```

Comment: Source: http://danielmiessler.com/study/lsof/

Comment: One good way is to use the cheat gem, if you use Ruby. It's just convenient, community-driven CLI to cheat-sheets of many utilities (language independent). Give it a [try](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/).

Answer (score 27):

```
lsof -i :port
```

will tell you what programs are listening on a specific port.

Comment: It's not limited to "listening", so if you specify `lsof -i :8080` and you have a bunch of processes connecting to a proxy on port 8080 you'll get those too.

Answer (score 14):

`lsof -i` will provide a list of open network sockets. The `-n` option will prevent DNS lookups, which is useful when your network connection is slow or unreliable.

Comment: `lsof -i` will *only* show you sockets that you have access to in your namespace (and which are regarded as "internet" sockets through introspection, not just any kind of network socket).  Otherwise handles of type 'sock' will not show up in the list.

Answer (score 14):

```
lsof +D /some/directory
```

Will display recursively all the files opened in a directory. +d for just the top-level.

This is useful when you have high wait% for IO, correlated to use on a particular FS and want to see which processes are chewing up your io.

Answer (score 13):

See what files a running application or daemon has open:

```
lsof -p pid
```

Where **pid** is the process ID of the application or daemon.

Answer (score 10):

```
lsof +f -- /mountpoint
```

lists the processes using files on the mount mounted at /mountpoint. Particularly useful for finding which process(es) are using a mounted USB stick or CD/DVD.