# How to capture network traffic by process name in mac?

Tags: macos, tcp, wireshark, packet-capture

I am trying to automate the process of capturing network packets send by a particular application.I don't have problem in windows as I am using Microsoft Network Monitoring tool and that gives all the traffic send based on the process.Now the problem is that we need to achieve the same result in mac as well.

We used Wire-shark in mac for capturing network traffic after a long research but still wireshark does not capture by process name.We tried some tools that captures based on process name but with very limited information. We need the full packet informations to be captured.

What will be the best way to achieve the result in mac as like we are getting in windows?

what all parameters can be used to filter the wanted data...?

I am in fact trying to get the port number used by the process but is that a right approach ? I am not sure we can zero down based on port number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lsof` command, but it's more complex than `netstat`.

Here is a guide: [lsof survival guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106234/lsof-survival-guide)